# dropdownlist empty value yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have tried to make dropdown list but why its just empety result?

This is the way i made the drop down

```
$form->field($model, 'ID_DATA_PROPERTIES')->dropDownList($list_properties, ['prompt'=>'-Choose a Course-'])
```

This `app/models/Request` :
i have table request

```
 * @property integer $ID_REQUEST
 * @property integer $ID_DATA_PROPERTIES //foreignkeys

 //request related to data_properties
 * @property DataProperties $iDDATAPROPERTIES

 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getIDDATAPROPERTIES()
{
    return $this->hasOne(DataProperties::className(), ['ID_DATA_PROPERTIES' => 'ID_DATA_PROPERTIES']);
}
```

The table data_properties : `ID_DATA_PROPERTIES`, `NAMA_DATA_PROPERTIES`

The controller :

```
 $model = new Requestdata();
 $list_properties = ArrayHelper::map(Requestdata::find()->all(), 'iDDATAPROPERTIES', 'NAMA_DATA_PROPERTIES');
```

Comment: Are you also trying to use a relationship there? It seems that one model is missing. Have you tried inspecting the sql generated by it?

Comment: yah i try to use relationship. but sometime it was work in view for viewing data its was like iDDATAPROPERTIES.NAMA_DATA_PROPERTIES. but it didnt work for this case?

Comment: @SyakurRahman hey thx you gave me idea, i made model with gii generator i was using wring model. hahaah ok thx for you notice

Comment: Pleasure. For the sake of future readers, you could post your solution as an answer, and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer, i was put wrong model.

i made dataproperties model by gii. and use it for find data list i need

```
 $list_properties = ArrayHelper::map(DataProperties::find()->all(), 'ID_DATA_PROPERTIES', 'NAMA_DATA_PROPERTIES');
```